# How to make a program declare variable number of indefinite size arrays

Tags: c++, c, arrays, loops, variable-length-array

This might sound crazy but I was wondering if it is possible to make a program declare `n` number of arrays of the type `array[]` in a loop using C/C++. For example, sample this pseudo-code:

```
input int _n_  

run loop for _n_ times such that:  
declare _array1[]_  
declare _array2[]_  
.  
.  
declare _array'n'[]_
```

So the problem here is two-fold:
- Declare variable length arrays
- Declare a variable number (i.e. *n* number of) such arrays.

Comment: C or C++? Choose one.

Comment: If you choose C++ why don't you have a look at STL containers like std::vector?

Comment: One question per post please. No one gets confused and everybody's happy. You have two separate, unrelated questions. Please consider two separate posts.

Comment: @n.m. Actually, one can write the solution in a nice neat matrix :P

Comment: This is not the data structure you are looking for. What is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @EricPostpischil The real problem used 2D arrays and Memoisation.

Comment: voted as "unclear what you're asking": I think he is asking for a jagged array (i.e. each row is able to be a different length), which is not possible using array syntax in C.   And if he is not asking for jagged, then just `int arr[n][k]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The truth table:

```
task        / language         | C                   | C++
-------------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------
Declare variable length arrays | Use VLAs            | not possible without
                               |      int arr[n];    | non-standard extensions
                               |                     | but use std::vector<T>
-------------------------------+---------------------+--------------------------
Declare a variable number      |  not possible but   | not possible but use
(i.e. n number of) such arrays |  use int arr[n][k]; | vector<vector<T>>
```

Comment: @MSalters: if you suggest the use of `vector<vector>`, you may as well add `int arr[n][k];`.

Comment: The place where I required this actually used 2D arrays and Memoisation.

Answer (score 2):

The way I understand it, if you want more than one array, couldn't you just use a 2D array? This of course means you don't have the variable length of an array, but you can have a variable amount of arrays with the same length.

Then you have this:

```
int n;
int array[n][length];
```

Comment: The place where I required this actually used 2D arrays and Memoisation.